# Object not found xampp

Tags: xampp

I have installed XAMPP on my machine, and i'm trying to access sub folders in htdocs but i'm getting the following error:

```
Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstall xampp and everything works fine.